# D3 line chart giving wrong values at highest number

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array of numbers sequentially rising from 15 to 20, then dropping to 16. From 15 to 19 they all display the correct position in the graph, but as soon as the subsequent number is lower it will display the wrong value.

Here is an example, as you can see it never hits 20 when the x-axis is on 5, rather around 19.7ish:
http://jsbin.com/yuzamuqile/edit?html,output

Anyone know what the issue might be?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're using "basis" for interpolation, which uses a beta spline to smooth out extreme peaks, which is what you're seeing.

Use "linear" to use straight lines rather than a curve.

```
                var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
                    .x(function(d) {
                        return xScale(d.time);
                    })
                    .y(function(d) {
                        return yScale(d.price);
                    })
                    .interpolate("linear");
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and helping me understand that this problem was related to interpolate! To achieve smooth curves without smoothing out extreme peaks is difficult then I suppose? The only option I can see is monotone, and it does not fully fulfill my criteria according to design..

Comment: You could try using "cardinal", which means that the curve will go through each of your points, at the cost of being slightly less "continuous", although it is still mathematically continuous as the first derivative at each point is the same either side of the point.

Comment: This site gives examples of each of the different types: http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/smoothing-out-lines-in-d3js.html

Comment: Cardinal is definitely the best option. Thanks again:)